# pip won't run after using sudo once to install a library

Tags: python, pip

I am not able to run `pip` without `sudo`. I get the following error:

```python
from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an usual problem when upgrading `pip`. Try this in order to avoid using `sudo`:

```bash
python -m pip install --user package
python3 -m pip install --user package
```